# Are the high voltages used in transmission lines responsible for 'arcing'.

Tags: electricity, voltage

I am just generally confused at the mechanism behind electrical arcing.

Comment: Are you referring to corona discharge? [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corona_discharge]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arcing happens when the electric field magnitude is high enough to ionize the molecules in the material. The minimum field that does this is called the *dielectric strength* of the material. For air, the dielectric strength is about $3\times 10^6\  {\rm V/m}$.

You could achieve breakdown with either a large potential difference across a large distance (as in lightning), or with a fairly modest potential difference across a small distance (as in switch contact arcing).

So, if you had two electrodes separated by air that produced a perfectly uniform field between them, you could create arcing with a $3 \times 10^6$ V difference at a distance of 1 m, or with a 3 V difference at a distance of 1 micron. In practice, arcing would occur at much lower potential difference because the field will concentrate around certain parts of the electrodes.